# Gridview bigger than Cellview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have created a gridview and some cell view to display. 
Set background color for gridview (green) and cellview (gray). 
Why the gridview background is bigger with all cell views ? 
It would make more sense if gridview cover all cell views or otherwise 
Can anyone please explain or help me.

[image]

Comment: are you having any sort of margin, padding?

Comment: don't have any padding or margin, that is why it's weird, so i ask this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is most likely generating xml layout in term of displaying.
However, this will not affect much on my code logic and functionality.
I have checked on most other devices. It is similar that way. It doesn't make sense also if need to display both color.
Hopefully guys can find a work around on this. Don't need focus too much on solving small issue and slow down the progress.